# What does it mean to say that "a topic is a distribution on words"?

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models

I was taking a machine learning course and they say the following two phrases that confuse me:

> each document is a distribution on topics.

and

> each topic is a distribution on words.

I was wondering if someone knew what that meant.

Here is a link to the notes:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/moitra/docs/bookex.pdf

---

Currently this is how I interpret it (my thoughts).

Well, we are modeling a topic as a vector $u^{(i)}$ with the relative frequencies of each word. So it just specifies how often each word appears in a specific topic. Also, each document can approximately thought of as a linear combination of these topic vectors, i.e. document $M_{j} = \sum^{r}_{i=1} w_{i}u^{(i)}$

thought I wasn't sure if that was right or how to include the concept of "distribution" to this.

Comment: I can find references to "distribution on words" at the top of p. 9 and at pp 19-20, but I see no reference to a "distribution on topics."  Could you please provide *accurate* quotations from your notes?

Comment: I won't lie but probably the second quote I heard during lecture. I can provide a link to the lecture video but I don't think I remember when it was said exactly: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsHbkVMaUGk&index=1&list=PLB3sDpSRdrOvI1hYXNsa6Lety7K8FhPpx

Answer (score 9):

Typically, in the context of Latent Dirichlet Allocation (used for Topic Modeling), we assume that the documents come from a generative process. I'll avoid math notation. Look at this figure:

[image: generative_process]

- (1) Every topic is generated from a Dirichlet distribution of $V$ dimensions where $V$ is the size of your vocabulary.
- (2) For every document:

  - (2.1) Generate a distribution over topics from a Dirichlet distribution of $T$ dimensions where $T$ is the number of topics in the corpus.
  - (2.2) For every word in the document:

    - (2.2.1) Choose a topic according to the distribution generated at (2.1)
    - (2.2.2) Choose a word according to the distribution corresponding to the chosen topic (generated at (1))

The rigorous mathematical explanaition is [here](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BleiNJ03.pdf) (section 3).

So, each topic is a probability distribution over the words of the vocabulary (1) because it says the probability, in that topic, of the word "dog" to appear.

And each document has a probability distribution over topics (2.1) which says from which topics the document is more likely to draw its words. We say that a document is a *mixture of topics*

**Note:**

- A Dirichlet distribution of three dimensions draws thinks like [0.2,0.4,0.4], [0.3,0.3,0.4], etc. which can be used as Categorical distributions.  This is why it is used to generate distributions over $V$ words (topics), and distributions over $T$ topics. See left and right sides of the figure.